# Wifi not working with Linux Mint 18.1 in Samsung NP900

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, wifi

I just got a Samsung NP900 and I erased everything and installed Linux Mint 18.1. While installing, I chose the option to install third-party software (and nothing else; meaning I didn't mess with the secure boot settings and stuff like that).

The installation went smoothly, but when I boot everything I can't get the wifi to get recognized. The output of `rfkill list` only lists the Bluetooth, but nothing else. (By the way, I don't have access to any cable internet, so I can't really test the cable connection on it).

Here's the output of `inxi -N`:

```
Network:    Card: Intel Device 24fd
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I'm running `x86_64`.

The output of `lspci -nn` gives me this version for the Networks controller:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
```

Comment: Please post output of `inxi -N`

Comment: @Luka Just edited in the question. Only one card is showing and no driver. Could this be used to my advantage? https://askubuntu.com/a/859263

Comment: Try finding your wireless card with `lspci -nn`
We need model and manufacturer of WiFi card so i can give you driver to install. Also you didn't wrote is your Linux Mint arch or not.
Type `arch` and if output is `x86_64` that means you are 64bit.

You can also try connecting to LAN and doing `sudo apt-get upgrade && apt-get update` that my find correct missing drivers.

Comment: @Luka just added to the question. I have to type by hand with my other computer, because I can't access the internet with the new one. I was wondering if just upgrading my kernel would work (and if it's easier).

Comment: This issue is about internal WiFi card not external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved the problem was upgrading the Kernel to version 4.9. Basically all I did was download the headers and image [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9/), pass them on to the new laptop via flashdrive and install them with `dpkg -i *deb`. A couple of error messages [like this one](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242078) but I think they weren't important, since everything is working fine.

After the new Kernel was installed, I installed the newer 4.10 kernel through the update manager, so that it can have a proper update-receiving installation.

Comment: It is better to install the new kernel through `apt` , a custom kernel doesn't receive a security update , Installing the 4.6 or 4.10 kernel from the regulary linux-mint repo will solve your problem

Comment: I didn't know that custom kernels didn't receive security updates. But I was planning on updating the kernel through `apt` anyway, now that I _can_ access the internet. I'll include that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix for you, but you need to connect your laptop to internet by using LAN cable.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/12/18/backports-20151218.tar.gz
tar -zvxf backports-20151218.tar.gz
cd backports-20151218
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

**EDIT:**
Since you do not have Ethernet....

Download https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/12/18/backports-20151218.tar.gz and place file to your usb flash drive, then place it from flash drive on your Linux Mint Desktop...
Execute:

```
cd ~/Desktop
tar -zvxf backports-20151218.tar.gz
cd backports-20151218
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and post output of

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

If it works, a kernel update will break wireless and you will need to repeat process (after tar command)

Comment: I just realized I don't have an ethernet port, so I'll buy an adaptor, try to find cable internet and port the results. This means that upgrading to a newer kernel won't fix the problem, right?

Comment: I do not it might fix it, but what I found out is that driver is not available in mint for your card. 

You do not have ethernet? Well you must have flash drive.
I'll edit my answer in a minute, let me know when you try it.

Comment: I've run into a larger problem, detailed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360683/installing-linux-on-a-samsung-np900-ultrabook) (if you're interested). After I solve that I'll try your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I wasn't able to complete your command because there were some package dependencies. I was able to make everything work by upgrading to Linux 4.9 kernel, though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official website](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) the [Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/8086/24fd) will work on the 4.6 kernel version and higher

1) Upgrade your kernel version : the 4.8 and the 4.10 kernel is available for linux mint.

2) Install the wifi driver

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0
cp iwlwifi* /lib/firmware
modprobe iwlwifi
```